# Parse this JSON

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, ios5

I got a small problem with parsing this JSON

```
    {
    "@attributes": {
        "date": "23-12-2012"
    },

    "data": [

        {
        "ft_link": "google",
        "title": "CEO"

        },
        {
        "ft_link": "Yahoo",
        "title": "CEO"
        }
     ]
}
```

I tried to get all the 'title' items.

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];


NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]);
```

This logs the whole JSON. But now i want to parse al the 'title' items. So i tried:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

But then it crashing, how can i parse it correctly?

The crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91583c0'
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned `objectForKey` doesn't work on NSArrays. However NSArrays do implement `valueForKey`, and you can use it to get what you want, `, ie:

```
[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"title"]
```

This will return an array of strings containing the titles.

The `objectForKey` call will return the array, while calling `valueForKey` on an array returns an array of objects by calling `valueForKey` on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Data is an [array](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) (of dictionaries), so it doesn't support `objectForKey:`. The error it crashes with likely would suggest such. You should also always check for any errors returned by the parsing of the json before attempting to do work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is a valid JSON or not.

But as per your requirement, you want to get all the values for "title". And I see there are multiple "titles", so either you need to break it into `NSArray` and then access the nested `NSDictinary` by `objectForKey:@"title"`.